# narrow down type of object value based on other known object value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type the return of a function so if a boolean (`loading` in this case) is `false` the rest of the returned object is known. If loading is `true` the rest of the object is `undefined`. I've tried the following:

```js
const someFun = ():
  | { loading: true; output: undefined }
  | { loading: false; output: string } => {
  const loading = Math.random() >= 0.5

  if (loading) {
    return { loading, output: undefined }
  } 
    return { loading, output: 'hello world' }

}

const { loading, output } = someFun()

if (!loading) {
  console.log(output)
}
```

I'm trying to get to the point that within the `if (!loading)` `output` is known to be a string. However right now typescript thinks at this point `output` could be `string | undefined`. Is there a way to set this up so that output within the if block is always just `string`?

Comment: This is a known limitation of TS's flow typing - change your assignment to `const result = someFun()` and your test and your log should work (`if (!result.loading) console.log(result.output)`)